# Transferring meta data from sharepoint 2007 to sharepoint 2010

Tags: managed-metadata

I am currently in the process of migrating from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 and i have run in to a snag. I have not found a reliable way to transfer over meta data for documents and lists. My company uses this meta data for version control so it is very important that I am able to transfer this data over.

Every time I have tried transferring any documents over it says the created date etc. is the date of the transfer. Is there a way to transfer this data from 2007 to 2010?

Comment: How have you done the upgrade? Methods such as database attach and inplace should preserve this metadata.

Comment: I actually just created a new instance of SharePoint 2010 as the old SharePoint 2007 is still in use. How do I access the methods database attach and inplace?

Comment: Here's some info about the database attach method. It's a bit involved, but conceptually simple task: detach the content database from 2007, attach it to the 2010 environment, run the upgrade. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303311.aspx

Comment: @JamesLove We are actually using SharePoint 2010 server and not foundation. Also I would like to be able to transfer specific content with meta data attached and not the whole database.

Comment: Ah sorry, just copied the link I still had open in another tab for another question on here. There's a similar page for attach Server 2010 databases, too. As for transferring specific content, see an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, try Chris O'Brien's Content Deployment Wizard for transferring individual libraries or documents/items: http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need. I will give this a try tomorrow, Thank you.

Comment: please can you tell me if this tool works for you im facing the same problem and im trying to backup the whole webapplication and restore it in a nother server just to do the export and import for the document library

Comment: I ended up using Metavis Mirgrator, it costs a pretty penny but it preserves the meta data perfectly. http://www.metavistech.com/product/sharepoint-migration